# Tail probability of the $\chi^2$ distribution

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Ho to prove that

$$
\int_{2s\epsilon^{-2}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(d/2)2^{d/2}}x^{d/2-1}e^{-x/2}dx \leq const.\epsilon^{-d}\exp(-\epsilon^{-2}s)
$$
holds for $\epsilon >0$ sufficiently small? Here $s>0$ is fixed and $\Gamma$ is the gamma function, and $d$ is a positive integer.

(taken from p.80 of Random Perturbations of Dynamical, by Freidlin et al, 3ed)

I expect the bound to come out of the Chernoff-Markov method: $P(|X|>a)\leq e^{-\lambda a}Ee^{\lambda |X|}$, $\lambda >0$ but I am not getting that bound exactly.

Comment: The Maple code $$int(x^{(1/2)*d-1}*exp(-(1/2)*x), x = 2*s/eps^2 .. infinity)\, assuming \,d::posint,eps>0 $$ produces a long output in terms of $WhittakerM .$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta=s/\epsilon^2$, then the change of variable $x=2\theta(1+y)$ yields that the integral of interest is
$$
\frac{\mathrm e^{-\theta}\theta^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}K(\theta),\qquad K(\theta)=\int_0^{\infty}(1+y)^{d/2-1}\mathrm e^{-\theta y}\mathrm dy.
$$
and the upper bound you are interested in holds if $K(\theta)\leqslant C$ for every $\theta$ large enough. Since $K(\ )$ is decreasing, this inequality holds for every $\theta\geqslant1$, with $C=K(1)$.

Comment: A longer soln.: let $X\sim \chi ^2$ distribution, $d$ deg. of freedom. For $\lambda >0$, Chernoff-Markov yields
\begin{eqnarray}
\mbox{wanted integral}=P(\epsilon^2X>2s)
&\leq& e^{-\lambda 2s}Ee^{\lambda \epsilon^2X}\\
&=& e^{-\lambda 2s}(1-2\lambda \epsilon^2)^{-d/2} \mbox{  mgf}\\
&\leq& \inf_{\lambda >0}\{e^{-\lambda 2s}(1-2\lambda \epsilon^2)^{-d/2}\}
\end{eqnarray}

Use calculus and get the optimal $\lambda=\frac{1}{2\epsilon^2}-\frac{d}{4s}$; substituting, we get the optimal bound
$$
e^{d/2}(\frac{d}{2s})^{-d/2}\epsilon^{-d}e^{-s/\epsilon^2}.
$$

Legit. mgf for small enough $\epsilon>0$.